# Scraping images from a website but the image is loaded from some server with javascript

Tags: python, scrapy-splash

I am trying to scrape the image and the price from this url:

https://www.woolworths.co.za/prod/Food/Fruit-Vegetables-Salads/Salads-Herbs/Cucumbers/English-Cucumber-300-g-650-g/_/A-20004019

using scrapy and scrapy-splash.

The problem that I am running into is that it seems like the price and image are fetched from somewhere using javascript (if I load the webiste in chrome and disable javascript, I can't see either of the elements and of course, they don't show up if I use scrapy.Request).

I have tried using scrapy_splash.SplashRequest but still no luck. Please help.

Here is the code for my spider

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class Myspider(scrapy.Spider):
      name = 'WooliesSpider'
      def __init__(self):
          self.headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"}
      # download_delay = 10.0
      item_dict = {}
      # handle_httpstatus_list = [301]
      base_url = 'https://www.woolworths.co.za'
    
      def get_category_from_link(link):
          base = "https://www.woolworths.co.za/cat/Food/"
          text_after_base = link[:len(base)]
          category = text_after_base[:text_after_base.find('/')]
          return category
      def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.woolworths.co.za/dept/Food/_/N-1z13sk5'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse)

      def parse(self,response):
          containers = response.css('div.lazyload-container.landing__block.landing__block--half-fourth')
          #print(containers)
          link_tags = [c.css('a.landing__link') for c in containers]
          #print(link_tags[0])
          link = link_tags[0]
          url = self.base_url+link.attrib['href']
          print(url)
          yield SplashRequest(url,callback=self.parse_product_page)
          
        #   for link in link_tags:
        #       url = self.base_url+link.attrib['href']
        #       print(url)
        #       yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse_product_page)
              #input()

      def parse_product_page(self,response):
          print('parse_product_page')
          items = response.css('div.product-list__item')
          item = items[0]
          link = item.css('a.product--view').attrib['href']
          url = self.base_url+link
          print(url)
          yield SplashRequest(url=url,callback=self.parse_item_page,endpoint='render.html',
            args={'wait':0.5})
        
        # yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse_item_page)
        #   for item in items:
        #       link = item.css('a.product--view').attrib['href']
        #       url = self.base_url+link
        #       print(url)
        #       input()
        #       yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse_item_page)

      def parse_item_page(self,response):
          print('*****parse_item_page*****')

          print(response.css('figure.zoom'))
          print(response.css('span.price'))
```

And here is the output from the console

```
2021-07-18 21:49:11 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.5.0 started (bot: SavR-Bot)
2021-07-18 21:49:11 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 19.10.0, Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019), cryptography 2.8, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
2021-07-18 21:49:11 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2021-07-18 21:49:11 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'SavR-Bot',
 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1.2,
 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter',
 'HTTPCACHE_STORAGE': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'Scrapers.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['Scrapers.spiders'],
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, '
               'like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'}
2021-07-18 21:49:11 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 875e1f88a8eb7813
2021-07-18 21:49:11 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2021-07-18 21:49:14 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapyjs.SplashMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2021-07-18 21:49:15 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2021-07-18 21:49:15 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2021-07-18 21:49:15 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-07-18 21:49:15 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-07-18 21:49:15 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2021-07-18 21:49:15 [py.warnings] WARNING: c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\scrapy_splash\request.py:41: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function to_native_str. Use to_unicode instead.
  url = to_native_str(url)

2021-07-18 21:49:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.woolworths.co.za/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2021-07-18 21:49:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://localhost:8050/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2021-07-18 21:49:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.woolworths.co.za/dept/Food/_/N-1z13sk5 via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
https://www.woolworths.co.za/cat/Food/Food-Cupboard/International-Cuisine/_/N-1ele3tm
2021-07-18 21:49:31 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.woolworths.co.za/cat/Food/Food-Cupboard/International-Cuisine/_/N-1ele3tm via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
parse_product_page
https://www.woolworths.co.za/prod/Food/Food-Cupboard/Pasta-Rice-Grains/Pasta/Spaghetti-500-g/_/A-6009178658413
2021-07-18 21:49:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.woolworths.co.za/prod/Food/Food-Cupboard/Pasta-Rice-Grains/Pasta/Spaghetti-500-g/_/A-6009178658413 via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
*****parse_item_page*****
[]
[]
2021-07-18 21:49:36 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-07-18 21:49:36 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1874,
 'downloader/request_count': 5,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 4552254,
 'downloader/response_count': 5,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 21.456216,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 18, 19, 49, 36, 851956),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 5,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 6,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 6,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 6,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 6,
 'splash/render.html/request_count': 3,
 'splash/render.html/response_count/200': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 18, 19, 49, 15, 395740)}
2021-07-18 21:49:36 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```